# Show HTML Source Code via PHP or Java

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to do something that should be pretty simple.

I currently have a php form that takes the field entries and simply places them in a html style table on the output page. This page has zero styling since the CSS does that and after I output the table, I view the source code in Chrome and then copy and paste it into my email templates to send out ranking tables in my emails.

Now, I have someone else doing this same process but they are using Safari and not chrome. The same can be achieved but rather trying to explain this process to them, I would like to a incorporate a better solution.

On the same page that would display the table (with which I view the source code), Would there be a way to display the html source itself? Thus eliminating the need to manually view the source after the page has been rendered?

The exact code I'm using is:

```
<?php
echo"
<!-- NIGHTLY RANKING 7:00 PM -->
";
echo "
<table class=\"nightly_ranking\">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class=\"table_center\" colspan=\"3\">".$_POST['field_venue']." ".$_POST['field_date']." 7:00 PM Game</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=\"table_center table_alternate\"><b>Place</b></td>
<td class=\"table_center table_alternate\"><b>Player Name</b></td>
<td class=\"table_center table_alternate\"><b>Points</b></td>
</tr>";
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_2']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">1st</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_2']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_3']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_6']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">2nd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_6']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_7']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_10']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">3rd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_10']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_11']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_14']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">4th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_14']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_15']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_18']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">5th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_18']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_19']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_22']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">6th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_22']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_23']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_26']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">7th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_26']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_27']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_30']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">8th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_30']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_31']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_34']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">9th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_34']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_35']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_38']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">10th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_38']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_39']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_42']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">11th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_42']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_43']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_46']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">12th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_46']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_47']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_50']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">13th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_50']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_51']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_54']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">14th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_54']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_55']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_58']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">15th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_58']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_59']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_62']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">16th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_62']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_63']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_66']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">17th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_66']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_67']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_70']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">18th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_70']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_71']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_74']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">19th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_74']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_75']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_78']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">20th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_78']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_79']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_82']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">21st</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_82']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_83']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_86']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">22nd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_86']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_87']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_90']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">23rd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_90']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_91']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_94']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">24th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_94']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_95']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_98']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">25th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_98']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_99']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_102']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">26th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_102']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_103']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_106']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">27th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_106']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_107']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_110']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">28th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_110']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_111']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_114']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">29th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_114']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_115']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_118']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">30th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_118']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_119']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_122']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">31st</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_122']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_123']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_126']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">32nd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_126']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_127']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_130']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">33rd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_130']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_131']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_134']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">34th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_134']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_135']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_138']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">35th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_138']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_139']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_142']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">36th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_142']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_143']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_146']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">37th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_146']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_147']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_150']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">38th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_150']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_151']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_154']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">39th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_154']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_155']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N1_158']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">40th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_158']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N1_159']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
echo "
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- /NIGHTLY RANKING 7:00 PM -->

<!-- NIGHTLY RANKING 9:30 PM -->
";
echo "
<table class=\"nightly_ranking\">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class=\"table_center\" colspan=\"3\">".$_POST['field_venue']." ".$_POST['field_date']." 9:30 PM Game</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=\"table_center table_N2_alternate\"><b>Place</b></td>
<td class=\"table_center table_N2_alternate\"><b>Player Name</b></td>
<td class=\"table_center table_N2_alternate\"><b>Points</b></td>
</tr>";
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_2']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">1st</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_2']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_3']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_6']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">2nd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_6']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_7']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_10']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">3rd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_10']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_11']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_14']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">4th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_14']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_15']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_18']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">5th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_18']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_19']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_22']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">6th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_22']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_23']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_26']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">7th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_26']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_27']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_30']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">8th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_30']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_31']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_34']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">9th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_34']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_35']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_38']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">10th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_38']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_39']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_42']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">11th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_42']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_43']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_46']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">12th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_46']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_47']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_50']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">13th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_50']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_51']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_54']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">14th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_54']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_55']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_58']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">15th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_58']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_59']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_62']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">16th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_62']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_63']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_66']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">17th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_66']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_67']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_70']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">18th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_70']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_71']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_74']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">19th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_74']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_75']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_78']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">20th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_78']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_79']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_82']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">21st</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_82']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_83']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_86']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">22nd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_86']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_87']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_90']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">23rd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_90']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_91']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_94']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">24th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_94']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_95']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_98']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">25th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_98']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_99']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_102']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">26th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_102']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_103']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_106']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">27th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_106']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_107']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_110']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">28th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_110']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_111']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_114']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">29th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_114']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_115']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_118']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">30th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_118']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_119']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_122']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">31st</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_122']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_123']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_126']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">32nd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_126']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_127']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_130']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">33rd</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_130']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_131']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_134']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">34th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_134']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_135']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_138']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">35th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_138']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_139']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_142']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">36th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_142']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_143']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_146']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">37th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_146']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_147']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_150']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">38th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_150']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_151']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_154']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">39th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_154']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_155']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field_N2_158']))
{
echo
"<tr>
<td class=\"table_center\">40th</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_158']."</td>
<td class=\"table_center\">".$_POST['field_N2_159']."</td>
</tr>
";
}
echo "
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- /NIGHTLY RANKING 9:30 PM -->
;"
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach is to escape the HTML to be displayed using HTML entities and then rendering it by echoing / printing it.

- For PHP, you can use [PHP's htmlentities() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).
- For Java, you can use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) or [htmlEscape from Spring HtmlUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html).

Here is a short PHP example. This is wrapped in a `<pre>` tag to display as [preformatted text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) which is useful for formatting purposes.

```
<pre><?php

    $table = '<table><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>';
    echo htmlentities($table);

?></pre>
```

If you want syntax highlighting, you can add a library like [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/).

Comment: This seems to work nicely. Now if I can just wrap the massive table code into it. Also, I am passing variables. What is the syntax for adding in variables into the string?

P.S. I edited the original question to add the exact php code I'm using.

Comment: For your code, a simple approach is to just add `htmlentities()` to each `echo` command. For example `echo htmlentities("<tr>...</tr>");`

Comment: Thank you so much Grokify! This works absolutely perfect!

Answer (score 0):

you can put the html code into a textarea or xmp tag,like

```html
<textarea>
<h1>title</h1>
</textarea>

<xmp>
<h1>title</h1>
</xmp>
```

Comment: Mozilla discourages the use of the <xmp> tag with the following warning: "Obsolete: This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it." More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp